# PyDev: "Unresolved import nltk" When running, pydev imports it

Tags: import, python-2.7, pydev, nltk

I want to get rid of this error message and I want to have the benefits of auto completion and suggestions. PyDev obviously does find nltk, because when running it from inside the IDE it works. Not only from console.

Surely someone needs to know why I got this "unresolved import" error message but on the other way when clicking on "run" it works perfectly well.

Answer (score 3):

@TheGT seems to be on the correct path, though I found the instructions a little confusing. My solution:

Project->Properties->PYDEV-PYTHONPATH->External Libraries

Add source folder (button)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk-2-0/4-py2.7.egg

Obviously, your path, version, etc... could be different.

Here's what seems odd.
There's a button to add zip/jar/egg and that doesn't want to work correctly with the nltk...directory...egg. The nltk egg behaves like a directory in the chooser (i.e. continues to drill down rather than return).

On the other hand, the source folder button does allow you to choose a folder... so I chose the egg and that seems to work.

It seems like the nltk egg is not configured correctly for OSX.  And, depending on how it is accessed, it can behave like a folder or a final destination.

NOTE: Adding the nltk egg into the external libraries path of your project makes the error go away. But adding the egg into preferences>PyDev>Interpreter does not appear to resolve the problem (on it's own).

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact same error when I was trying to use nltk in my project. I did 2 things to resolve the unresolved error to go away.

1. I added the setupctools**.egg file (the file that is used to install nltk in mac/*nix systems) as an external library
   [Project->Properties->PYDEV-PYTHONPATH->External Libraries]
   I am using Eclipse Indigo, and Python 2.6.1 on my mac btw.
2. I restarted the eclipse

Bam! - the error goes away.

Although, the error is not there anymore, I would like to know why Eclipse was behaving this way. The strange thing to note was that when I tried to run the program, the program did run successfully, even though eclipse marked "import nltk" as unresolved import.